# exception on string with menu selection (Java)

Tags: java

I have an assignment that I need to validate that an input (String) is valid and if not throw an exception. When I have my there is a menu option (1-6) and when they select 2, which is to enter a new monkey it will skip the user entering input and jump straight to the error. If i move my variable after the try{ then it still doesnt allow any input and has an error because this variable is needed lower down. Any help of how to get this to work would be great. Thanks

```
public static void intakeNewMonkey(Scanner scanner) {
    
    System.out.println("What is the monkey's name?");
    String monkeyName = scanner.nextLine();
    
    try{
        
        if(!monkeyName.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$")){
            throw new Exception("is wrong input!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("perfect!");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Without knowing what you need the `monkeyName` for after the `try/catch` your best course of action is to initialize `String monkeyName = null;` (or Optional) before the try/catch then check it after.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the `monkeyName` before the `try` block then you will be able to use if after the `try...catch` block.

```
System.out.println("What is the monkey's name?");
String monkeyName = null;

try{
    monkeyName = scanner.nextLine();
    
    if(!monkeyName.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$")){
        throw new Exception("is wrong input!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("perfect!");
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}

// use monkeyName here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but I'm guessing that the problem is not in the code you posted but in the code that you didn't post.

You say that your application has a menu and the user selects a menu option by entering a number. So I assume that you use method [nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) for accepting the user selection and then you immediately call your `intakeNewMonkey` method and pass it the same `Scanner` that you use to get the user's menu selection. In that case, the call to method `nextLine`, in method `intakeNewMonkey`, is reading the [newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891773/what-does-the-newline-character-mean-to-computer) that was entered by the user when she hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after entering the menu selection. Hence variable `monkeyName` is an empty string – which is not valid – and that causes the exception to be thrown.

After calling `nextInt` and before calling `nextLine` (to receive more input from the user), you need to call `nextLine` to get rid of the unwanted newline. Refer to this SO question: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

If my description of your application is correct, then in the code that accepts the user's menu selection, after calling method `nextInt` and before calling `intakeNewMonkey` I would add a call to `nextLine` (and ignore the value it returns).